# Hardhat: Order of execution of Multiple scripts inside scripts folder?

Tags: truffle, hardhat, truffle-migration

In Truffle, we can have multiple deployment scripts inside the migrations folder, like `01_deploy.js`, `02_deploy.js` and truffle executes them in ascending order of the starting number, ie:

1. `01_deploy.js`, then
2. `02_deploy.js`

I am trying to understand if Hardhat also provides this sort of guarantee in order of execution of deployment scripts inside the `scripts` folder ?

Otherwise, If I have multiple deployment scripts (from a truffle project for example), then how do I order them in Hardhat ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it does execute them in order like that too

Comment: vanilla Hardhat will do that? or do I need the "hardHat-deploy" plugin?

Comment: yes. no plugin needed. e.g. `npx hardhat test` runs the tests in order